# Contacts analogue to UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, contacts

In iOS 11+, `UIImagePickerController` can be used to access the user's photo library without asking permission because it runs as a separate process and does not pose the privacy risk of an app accessing all of the information in the user's photo library without their consent.

Does an analogue to this process exist for fetching a user's contacts?

Example scenario: app needs to know a specific contact's email address but it does not need to see the entire address book. Is there something like a `UIContactsController` which can allow the user to open contacts without a permission prompt, select an email address, which then is passed back read-only to the host app?

Comment: Not seeing one.  Good idea though!  Be a great thing to ask for as a UIKit enhancement via bugreporter.apple.com

Comment: If you wouldn't mind upvoting, then maybe it will get more visibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exists with the `CNContactPickerViewController` framework. No permission is required as the app only receives the user's final contact selection.